# Page Builder issue in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, page-builder

TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\PageBuilder\Plugin\Filter\TemplatePlugin::afterFilter() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/falcon/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146 and defined in /var/www/html/falcon/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Plugin/Filter/TemplatePlugin.php:42 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/falcon/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146):

Facing this error on the product detail page.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a custom module on the product detail page. Please disable all custom modules on the product page and try again. This will make it easier for you to determine the cause of the problem.